# Use pushViewController on separate table delegate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, pushviewcontroller

in *PrimaryViewController.h* I have an `IBOutlet` attached to the table I added in the .xib file

```
IBOutlet UITableView *table;
```

in PrimaryViewController.m I construct a new tableController from my TableDataController class and attach it to the table

```
tableController = [[TableDataController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
//Attach the table controller as datasource and delegate to the table
[table setDelegate:tableController];
[table setDataSource:tableController];
```

Now all data in the table is coming from tableController. Since PrimaryViewController is the class being pushed to the stack of the navigationController and not the TableDataController class; using:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController];
```

in *tableController* results in nothing as *tableController* has no *navigationController*. It is *PrimaryViewController* who can use the *navigationController*.

What I want to be able to do is to use the function `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` in TableDataController to push a new view controller onto the stack of the PrimaryViewController.

Please note: I cannot `#import "ParimaryViewController.h"`
into my TableDataController.h so I can send its (*PrimaryViewController*) object --  they will then be cross-importing each other, creating a semantic error.

PrimaryViewController is a regular class that extends UIViewController class with a .xib nothing special.
TableDataController is a regular class that extends UITableViewController class with **no** .xib file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import the `PrimaryViewController` header into TableDataController.**m** to avoid an import cycle.

Your `TableDataController` simply needs a reference to the `PrimaryViewController`. All you have to do is add a property to `TableDataController`, and set it right after the data controller is created.

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) PrimaryViewController * viewController;
```

In order to be able to use that class name, you need to add a forward declaration right below the imports in TableDataController.h:

```
@class PrimaryViewController;
```

This lets the compiler know that there is such a class and you will be referring to it in this header file, but it will be defined elsewhere.

Synthesize the property as usual. When you create the `TableDataController`, you set that property to point to the creating view controller:

```
tableController = [[TableDataController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
[tableController setViewController:self];
```

Now you can message the view controller in the `TableDataController`'s methods by accessing that property:

```
[self.viewController pushViewController:newViewController];
```

Comment: Thanks Josh,
I have just tried to do that and I still have some issues. Isn't there any other way to do what I'm trying to do
i.e. use pushViewController from a different class? This must be something that was done before I would think.

Comment: It's extremely hard to say without some more info in your question. What exactly are the issues? The main problem I see is: how is your `TableDataController` getting a reference to the view controller in the first place? Where is it created? In the xib, or in code? Can you edit your question to include a bit more about the structure here?

Comment: thank you so much. Can't believe it's this easy. It's been frustrating me for days.